# Book, The Host by Stephanie Meyer, child sex abusers from space?

Tags: the-host

In the book by Stephanie Meyer, the action happens a couple of years after the whole world has been taken over by alien body snatchers who live in their hosts' brains.

There are isolated groups of free humans desperately trying to hide.

The protagonist is in a teen girl's body and, unusually, is in communication with her host instead of deleting her personality.

I am somewhat confused by a line in this extract. Do alien brain worms also molest kids?

> "That’s how we realized you were here, you know" she said, thinking of the sickening news headlines again. 
>   When the evening news was nothing but inspiring human-interest stories, when pedophiles and junkies were lining up at the hospitals to turn themselves in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the aliens themselves aren't child molesters or drug users (at least, not that we know of). We've seen that the aliens have difficulty with host personalities. The host personality can influence the alien's own personality and behavior, and take control of their body during times when their guard is down. Obviously, this is most prominent with the protagonist, but other aliens, notably the main antagonist, have a similar issue. As such, an alien in the body of a pedophile or someone addicted to drugs would not be able to control their desires of their host all the time. Thus, the aliens would go to the hospital, hoping to either modify their host's behavior, whether through advanced alien technology or regular human therapy, or to contain them to prevent harm to themself or others.

It's also possible that, being very societally utopian (among themselves, anyway) they'd be shocked by these tendencies. So it's also possible that the aliens simply want to be removed from such troublesome hosts as soon as possible. But, given the juxtaposition with human interest stories, the previous explanation seems more likely: the aliens are just acting in the most utopian fashion possible.